# Segmentation fault when I pipe stdout to my program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pipe

I don't know if I have to tell it again, but english is not my native language and I'm not a very good student, I've seen you are able to correct my message so it's fine but I'd like to apologize once again.

Here is the deal, I have a program, which convert a given graph passed in argument to Dimacs format that I'll store in a .cnf file. (We use it to solve it with a SAT-solver)

He's perfectly working when I use it by myself, so I'd like to have another program, graph_generator, that I'll pipe into myprogram to have random graphes.

I've made my graph_generator program, and he correctly prints graph at the format I want, so I've tried to do basically ./graph_generator | ./myprogram but I instantly get a segmentation fault, I can't see why, graph_generator returns exactly what it's expected, and when I want to use a debugger, I don't see how it's possible knowing that I pipe a result, when I copy paste the result of graph_generator myprogram correctly generates my .cnf file.

I don't know where the problem could come from, I have a theory but it's a bit lame, it's that the stdout of graph_generator, once piped myprogram considers the space as an argument and there is the problem. Anyone could help me please?

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  graph* mygraph;
  int taille, nbEdge;
  int i;
  FILE* resultat;


  printf("mark 1");
  taille = atoi(argv[1]);
  nbEdge = atoi(argv[2]);
  printf("mark 2");
  mygraph = build_empty_graph(taille);
  for(i = 3; i < argc; i+= 2)
    add_edge(atoi(argv[i]), atoi(argv[i+1]), mygraph);

  resultat = fopen("resultat.cnf", "w");
  write_result_comments(resultat);
  write_result_header(resultat, mygraph);
  write_first_stack(resultat, mygraph);
  write_second_stack(resultat, mygraph);
  fclose(resultat);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the main of myprogram, when I use it with the pipe, the message "mark1" doesn't even appears

Comment: No it won't do that.  Show the code where it segfaults.

Comment: I've tried to do some marks with printf, the segfault occurs before I've even tried to convert an argument with atoi.

Comment: Then the lines that you want to show start at 'main' and go to the atoi.

Comment: The problem is that part is really basic, I have only declared my variables (int size, nbEdge;)

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Either you can show some code or get voted down.

Comment: Maybe it's the parenthesis : (./graph_generator | ./myprogram)

Comment: Try changing to printf("mark 1\n");

Comment: With parenthesis it doesn't even start any of the two programs

Comment: I've changed to mark 1\n and effectively it appears now, the segfautl occurs after my first atoi then

Comment: It is your first atoi.  You are not passing any arguments.

Comment: the problem is the generator program outputs to a file, not to stdout,  So the command line needs to be changed to: (./graph_generator; ./myprogram < resultat.cnf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is segfaulting because you don't check argc and are passing no values as arguments.
Please note that stdin is a separate stream from the arguments in argv.

Best way to fix this is to build up hierarchically:

tokenizer: read stdin in a loop with getchar until you get to whitespace (space, tab or newline).

parser: atoi is fine, since you only pass ints.

state machine: first two args to taille and nbEdge, rest in pairs (x, y) to call the program.  Maybe use a switch statement and a state variable in a loop.

program: the rest of your program pretty much as is.

Comment: That's it, my pipe doesn't go into argv, so my program can't works,  is there a way to do so or I'll have to use the file descriptor for stdin ?